# POSTMAN export don't work with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler, command-line-interface, postman

I created a POST request on POSTMAN, it work great. But when I export header and form body in PHP cURL code and execute it with PHP CLI, the server does not show me data asked in my form.

Thereafter the PHP cURL exported with POSTMAN :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://renovation-info-service.gouv.fr/trouvez-un-professionnel",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",

  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "all%5Bcols-1%5D%5Bcode_postal%5D=03&all%5Bcols-1%5D%5Bcommune%5D=03&all%5Brayon%5D=5&all%5Bdomaine_travaux%5D=30&op=Localiser%2Bdes%2Bentreprises&form_build_id=form-48ViCRy2vxhZBo452cPiRi22VR7K2mZ5ZUwzR-tlO3U&form_id=front_office__locate_all_entreprise_form",

  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "accept-language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "connection: keep-alive",
    "content-length: 253",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cookie: UUID=3ab96f55-1e99-d7c4-39a9-59345773b4ca; has_js=1; _ga=GA1.3.1779497884.1533297982; _gid=GA1.3.1474901001.1533297982; _gat=1",
    "host: renovation-info-service.gouv.fr",
    "postman-token: 570c2dd8-8289-dacd-db57-dcb0d107ea29",
    "referer: http://renovation-info-service.gouv.fr/trouvez-un-professionnel",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1",
    "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Thank you for your help ! And sorry with my bad english ^^'

Comment: So what is the error that cURL produces?

Comment: There is no error but it's like my form wasn't sent. But in POSTMAN it work ...

Answer (score 0):

POSTMAN answer is a html code with data asked in POST request. PHP cURL answer is a html code without data asked in POST request.